# How to set up http routing tests with templates in relative paths?

Tags: go

I'm writing a small web app with gorilla/mux. My folder structure inside my `GOPATH` is like this.

```
app/
  - app.go
  - views/
    - layout.html
  - login/
    - login.go
    - login_test.go
    - login.html
```

I'd like to keep `login` as a completely separate package. Within `login.go` I initiate the template and render it on request. All file paths are relative to `app.go` as I run `go run app.go` in my main `app/` folder.

```
package login

var view = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(
  "login/login.html",
  "views/layout.html",
))

func GetLogin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  err := view.ExecuteTemplate(w, "layout", nil)
  check(err)
}
```

That works fine and I can call the route in my `app.go` file.

```
import (
  "github.com/zemirco/app/login"
)

func main() {

  router := mux.NewRouter()
  router.HandleFunc("/login", login.GetLogin).Methods("GET")
  http.Handle("/", router)
  http.ListenAndServe(":"+os.Getenv("PORT"), nil)

}
```

**My problem is testing this route**. Within `login_test.go` I have something like this.

```
package login

import (
  "net/http"
  "net/http/httptest"
  "testing"
  "."
)

func TestHandleGetLogin(t *testing.T) {
  request, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil)
  response := httptest.NewRecorder()
  login.GetLogin(response, request)
  t.Log(response)
}
```

Whenever I run `go test login/login_test.go` I get the error message

> open login/login.html: no such file or directory

As far as I know `go test` executes from within the `login/` directory and therefore cannot find the html files. The relative file paths are wrong.

How can I solve this problem or what would be a better directory structure?

Comment: Go test takes a _package_ not a file, try `go test ./login` to test the login pacakge. http://dave.cheney.net/2014/01/21/using-go-test-build-and-install

Comment: That doesn't work. I've created a repo to demonstrate my problem - https://github.com/zemirco/route-template-testing